# Python socket programming with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am new to socket programming with threads in python. I have a simple server app:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
import _thread

host = ''  
port = 52000 

sock = socket()
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5) 
print "server is waiting for connections.."
def clientthread():
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print addr, "is connected"
    conn.send('Hi! I am server\n') #send only takes string
    #Receiving from client
    data = conn.recv(1024) 
    print data

for num in range(5):
    Thread(target = clientthread).start() 

sock.close()
```

This simple code works perfectly for 5 clients and after that when one logs out and a new one wishes to contact with server, the application simply closes. But what I want is to have 5 simultaneous connections, and once anyone have logged out, one client space is recreated to accommodate the new one (i.e. 5th one currently). I believe threading module can help me here. Its functions like `acquire()` and `release()`. But not sure how? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your threads before closing your socket.
Currently, you are simply starting 5 threads and closing server socket right after.
Join will simply wait until `clientthread` returns.

[Python threading page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

> join([timeout])
>   Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.